# How to include color interpolate in this treemap?

Tags: d3.js

Can you help me color the boxes, such that they are changing according to the LScore2 value?

Needs to incorporate  d3.interpolateRdYlGn(t)

from : https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic

This is my block.

https://blockbuilder.org/a3igner/0658ea95abf9c7b729e16ca84906d6f1

Comment: You can't: your code uses D3 v3, while `d3.interpolateRdYlGn(t)` belongs to v4/v5.

Comment: I only realized it today. Thanks. I cloned an existing example on blocks. I managed to incorporate colors through an old v3 method. But I need to rewrite this code completely in v4. Am only learning thanks!